# USB disk doesn't work on the new kernel

Tags: linux, kernel, usb

I just install the latest linux kernel (3.12.6) on my laptop(Lenovo). My system is Ubuntu 12.04. I just use the old configuration file in the old system which is "config-3.2.0-58-generic". Everything is well unless the usb disk dose not work when i plug it in. The mouse can not work either but light. The trackpoint and touchpad work well.

There are some infos:

```
:dmesg|tail

[  524.745753] usb 1-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci

:lsblk

NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 298.1G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   1.5G  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0    81G  0 part 
├─sda3   8:3    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda4   8:4    0  15.6G  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0   160G  0 part 
├─sda6   8:6    0   1.9G  0 part [SWAP]
└─sda7   8:7    0  38.1G  0 part /
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom  

:fdisk -l

Disk identifier: 0x509ebf17

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048     3074047     1536000    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2         3074048   172939263    84932608    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       172941310   592371711   209715201    f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
Partition 3 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sda4       592371712   625139711    16384000    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda5       172941312   508483583   167771136    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda6       588359680   592371711     2006016   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda7       508485632   588349439    39931904   83  Linux


:mount
/dev/sda7 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc     (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
gvfs-fuse-daemon on /home/fan/.gvfs type fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=fan)
/dev/sda5 on /media/T type fuseblk  (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)
```

Seems like it is connecting to the computer. But nothing happen. The `/mnt` folder is empty.

Comment: What is the output of `cat /proc/partitions` ?

Comment: I have just added it. Thanks for your quick response. It is the same as `lsblk`

Comment: Can you give us the output of `sudo fdisk -l` ? And also that of `mount` ?

Comment: OK, I have added it.

Answer (score 0):

I have something like this since new re-installation.
I do these things:

1. `tail -f /var/log/syslog`
2. unplug the USB device
3. plug in the USB device
4. and I see this error:

   > Unix modprobe: FATAL:/modules.dep: No such file or directory /lib/modules/3.2.0-58-generic
5. Fortunally I can fix this because I have an old library with the command

   ```
   sudo ln /lib/modules/3.2.0-58-generic /lib/modules/3.2.0-57-generic
   ```

Comment: Thanks.But my problem seems different `mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 6: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3"
mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 6 was not an MTP device` I google it, but dose not fix still.